# Keras not seeing all images from training and validation folders

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm working on an image classification project in Keras. I currently have 2 classes with 1,440 images per class for training and 360 images pero class for validation, but when I start running the Keras model it only sees 206 images for training and 36 images for validation. I have checked and I have the correct location.

This is what the model sees:

[image: Images that Keras is seeing]

This is my training folder: 2,880 images in 2 folders, 1,440 per folder

[image]

This is my validation folder: 720 images in 2 folders, 360 per folder

[image]

Most of my images, probably like 99% of them, are *.jfif*, is it possible that that's what's causing the problem? If not, how can I fix this?

Comment: Hi @Jaime Miranda, interesting question! I was wondering, how did you pass your validation folder to the fit function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, having images in JFIF format is the problem. Keras' `ImageDataGenerator` does not support all image formats, you can see the whitelist [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/master/keras_preprocessing/image/iterator.py#L34), which currently contains PNG, JPG, JPEG, BMP, PPM, TIF, and TIFF extensions/formats. `ImageDataGenerator` will simply ignore image formats that it does not support.

You would need to convert your unsupported images to a supported format.

Comment: Thanks @Matias Valdenegro. Do you happen to know of a software or python script that would allow me to convert those JFIF images into a supported format in batches?